# Mongoose. Get document value in post hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose

About `mongoose` (NodeJS ORM). I try to use `pre` and `post` hooks. I have a `config` schema, and after `save` I want to call a `post` hook, to use `writeFile` on it. My code looks like this:

```
configSchema.post('save', function(result) {
  const config = {};
  Object.entries(this).forEach(([key, item]) => {
    if(key.charAt(0) !== '_') config[key] = item;
    console.log(`config[${key}] = ${config[key]}`);
  });

  const newConfig = JSON.stringify(config);
  const JSON_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '../config.json');
  return fs.writeFile(JSON_FILE, newConfig, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
});
```

But in this case `this` and `result` not return a final document and I dont know even where find him. How to get result of `save` in the `pre`  hook?

---

upd. I found solution in `this.toJSON()`

Now my code looks like:

```
configSchema.post('save', function(result) {
  const config = {};
  const oldConfig = this.toJSON();

  Object.entries(oldConfig).forEach(([key, item]) => {
    console.log(`key.charAt(0) === ${key.charAt(0)}`);
    if(key.charAt(0) !== '_') config[key] = item;
  });

  const newConfig = JSON.stringify(config);
  const JSON_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '../config.json');
  return fs.writeFile(JSON_FILE, newConfig, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can grab result from `this` with `toJSON`:

```
this.toJSON()
```